# How do I find out the cause of a this unique constraint violation?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

So, I have two sql tables, tableCurrent, and tableHistory.
Both have the same columns: id, lst_updt_ts (last updated timestamp), and data.
Difference is tableCurrent is its key as id, while tableHistory has a id of (id, lst_updt_ts)

Normally, what happens is that whenever a row gets updated in tableCurrent, before it does so it puts a copy of that row in tableHistory. However, I have noticed that someone when copying the data to tableHistory, did not copy the previous lst_updt_ts, and instead used SYS_TIMESTAMP.

This causes a problem with a system downstream because the tableHistory has entries from the timestamp is greater then what is in tableCurrent.

I have come up with a solution to maintain the order, with this sql call.
In essence, it takes values whose's lst_updt_ts is greater in the tableHistory then tableCurrent, and sets the lst_updt_ts to be 1 millisecond before its associated entry in tableCurrent.

```
Update dbuser.tableHistory lh
set lh.lst_updt_ts = (
-- set to change the history table entry to 1 millisecond behind current table's timestamp
select (h.lst_updt_ts)-(1/86400000) --removes 1 milisecond.
from dbuser.tableCurrent h
where h.id = lh.id
)
WHERE (lh.id, lh.lst_updt_ts) in 
--grab all whose history table's lst_updt_ts is greater then current table
(
Select larh.id, larh.lst_updt_ts
FROM dbuser.tableHistory larh, dbuser.tableCurrent lar
where larh.id = lar.id
and larh.lst_updt_ts >= lar.lst_updt_ts
);
```

However, when running it. It complains of a **unique constraint violation**. Now the lst_updt_ts is one of the primary keys, after checking it should not be possible that there by a conflicting lst_updt_ts before and after a check.

One thing to note is that only one entry for each id in tableHistory, is found to have a row whose's lst_updt_ts is greater then it's entry in tableCurrent.

So why is this coming up with a unique constraint violation? Not this run the Oracle Database.

Comment: Please edit the question, and show table structure with data types, and example data.

Comment: So you're sure the subquery in your `where` clause only has at most one result per ID, across the whole table? Do you have any history entries with timestamp earlier than the current entry, but exactly on that second - so current is 12:34:56.789 and there is a history record at 12:34:56.000 for that ID, as well as one later than the current one?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is probably this:

```
select (h.lst_updt_ts)-(1/86400000) --removes 1 milisecond.
```

The comment isn't quite correct, because performing arithmetic like that causes an implicit conversion of the timestamp value to a date. (Read more about [datetime/interval arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-E405BBC7-DA9A-4DF2-9F22-E60CB9EC0705) in the docs). The `update set` then implicitly converts the result back to a timestamp, but the difference is likely to be more than a millisecond:

```
with t (ts) as (
  select timestamp '2019-06-01 12:34:56.788' from dual
)
select ts, ts - 1/8640000, cast(ts - 1/8640000 as timestamp)
from t;

TS                      TS-1/8640000        CAST(TS-1/8640000ASTIME
----------------------- ------------------- -----------------------
2019-06-01 12:34:56.788 2019-06-01 12:34:56 2019-06-01 12:34:56.000
```

The `ts - 1/8640000` is a plain date, as you can tell from it not showing any fractional seconds. Casting back to a timestamp leaves the fractional seconds at zero.

So if you have an ID with an existing history record that happens to be at exactly that adjusted time, even if that is not the latest history record time for that ID and is before the current time for that ID, then you will end up with a clash. With a very basic setup of that scenario:

```
create table tablecurrent (
  id number,
  lst_updt_ts timestamp,
  constraint tab_curr_uniq unique (id)
);

insert into tablecurrent
select 1, timestamp '2019-06-01 12:34:56.789' from dual;

create table tablehistory (id number,
  lst_updt_ts timestamp,
  constraint tab_hist_uniq unique (id, lst_updt_ts)
);
insert into tablehistory
select 1, timestamp '2019-06-01 12:45:00.000' from dual
union all
select 1, timestamp '2019-06-01 12:34:56.000' from dual;
```

then your query gets ORA-01001, because updating the 12:45 history record to 12:34:56 clashes with the older row.

If you use an interval to adjust the time:

```
select h.lst_updt_ts - interval '0.001' second --removes 1 milisecond.
```

... then it stays as a timestamp:

```
Update tableHistory lh
set lh.lst_updt_ts = (
-- set to change the history table entry to 1 millisecond behind current table's timestamp
select h.lst_updt_ts - interval '0.001' second --removes 1 milisecond.
from tableCurrent h
where h.id = lh.id
)
WHERE (lh.id, lh.lst_updt_ts) in 
--grab all whose history table's lst_updt_ts is greater then current table
(
Select larh.id, larh.lst_updt_ts
FROM tableHistory larh, tableCurrent lar
where larh.id = lar.id
and larh.lst_updt_ts >= lar.lst_updt_ts
);

1 row updated.

select * from tablehistory;

        ID LST_UPDT_TS            
---------- -----------------------
         1 2019-06-01 12:34:56.788
         1 2019-06-01 12:34:56.000
```

You may also be able to do this as a merge:

```
merge into tablehistory th
using (
  select id, lst_updt_ts
  from tablecurrent
) tc
on (tc.id = th.id)
when matched then
update set th.lst_updt_ts = tc.lst_updt_ts - interval '0.001' second
where th.lst_updt_ts > tc.lst_updt_ts;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0b1674e417ef8798580820559a9b4bdb)

Of course, with either approach, it's also feasible that you have two history records for an ID that are exactly a millisecond apart, where the newer one is still ahead of the current record; in that case you would still get a constraint violation. It seems less likely that you'd be hitting that scenario though, as the gaps involved are so much smaller.

Answer (score 0):

needoriginalname, from the error you are generating an existing key value so I would look at Alex Poole's suggestion.  Also is the PK in both cases the single column identified?  If not, you would need to be more selective in your matching of history to current.

Comment: Forgot to mention.  If you are using PL/SQL code you should be able to add an exception block to your code so you can print out the PK values for which the error is generated.